# How to calculate average amount here using MS Access?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Table name is **Salary**(id(autonumber), employee_id(number), effective_from(date), Amount(number))

If Initial Salary is updated, then, one record is stored in the table.

So, If someone's salary is 1000, and from April it increased to 1500.

Then, Table values for that employee will be:

```
effective_from  Amount
1/1/2020        1000
1/4/2020        1500
```

Is it possible to get average salary for a given date range by SQL?

e.g from 1/1/2020 to 31/12/2020, average Salary should be ((1000 * 3) + (1500 * 9))/12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will generate the salary for each month using a system table:

```sql
PARAMETERS 
    [DateStart] DateTime, 
    [DateEnd] DateTime;
SELECT 
    Salary.employee_id, 
    Dozen.N AS Id, 
    DateAdd("m",[Dozen].[N],[DateStart]) AS DateMonth, 
    Salary.amount
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT Abs([id] Mod 12) AS N FROM MSysObjects) AS Dozen, 
    Salary
WHERE 
    ((Dozen.N) <= DateDiff("m",[DateStart],[DateEnd])) 
    AND 
    ((Salary.effective_from) = 
        (Select Top 1 T.effective_from 
        From Salary As T 
        Where 
            T.employee_id = [Salary].[employee_id] 
            And 
            T.effective_from <= DateAdd("m",[Dozen].[N],[DateStart]) 
        Order By 1 Desc)))
ORDER BY 
    Salary.employee_id, 
    DateAdd("m",[Dozen].[N],[DateStart]);
```

Output:

[image]

Now, use this query as source in an aggregate query calculation the average amounts, like:

```sql
SELECT 
    Salaries.employee_id, 
    Avg(Salaries.amount) AS AverageAmount
FROM 
    Salaries
GROUP BY 
    Salaries.employee_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access, you will need a calendar table for this.  With such a table, you can use a query such as this:

```
select avg(amount)
from (select c.*,
             (select top 1 t.amount
              from [table] as t
              where t.effective_from <= c.date and
                    t.employee_id = @employee_id
              order by t.effective_from desc
             ) as amount
      from calendar as c
      where c.date >= @date1 and c.date <= @date2
     ) c
```

Comment: thanks! but could you please explain the calendar table?